# Giving execution right to entrypoint script does not working in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, chmod

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.7-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev binutils \
    && apk add --no-cache proj-dev geos gdal

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Building the image works fine, but when I try a `docker run` after building the image I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

The line `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` doesn't seem to work because when I comment the   `ENTRYPOINT` statement, build the image then start a containerI can see that the execution right isn't added for that file.

Docker version is:

```
Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243
```

I tried replacing the `RUN chmod` line with a `--chmod=777` option to the `COPY` of the entrypoint and it didn't change anything.

Any idea why a `chmod +x` would fail in docker ?

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  Are you mounting something (`docker run -v` option, Compose `volumes:`) over the image's `/usr/src/app` directory?

Comment: @DavidMaze no there is no volume mounting.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by removing the chmod line and replacing the entrypoint line with the following:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This way there is no need for a execution right on the entrypoint script.

But I still don't know why the chmod doesn't work.